# Combine 2 2D arrays that both contain chars with java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

I have to write a code as a task for my university and we have to recreate Minesweeper with java and it has to be runned in the command line.
For the matchfield we have to make an array that looks in the end like this picture:

[Example how it sould look in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctsni.png)

And to choose the field we have to use the scanner.
For example if you want to chose field C3, you have to type into the scanner C3.
At the moment im struggleing a little bit with the field.

I had 2 ideas but both didn't work out very well. 
in the first try i tried to create everything with 2 for loops and 1 array but my problem was that I couldn't add 2 charrs, so I had the chars 0 to 9 and the charrs A to J.

In the second try I created 3 array, one with the numbers 0 to 9 and anothe array A to J and in the third array i wanted to combine both arrays. And now I'm wondering if this it's possible if I can acctually combine them in the way I want and if it's possible could somebody give me some help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Minesweeper {
  public static void main (String[] args) {



    char c = 'A';
    char d = '0';
    char e = '9';
    char f = 'J';

    char[][] feldz = new char[11][11];
    char[][] feldb = new char[11][11];
    char[][] feld = new char[11][11];
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
      if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
        feldz[i][j] = ' ';
        System.out.print(feldz[i][j] + " |");
      }
      if (d > e) {
        d = '0';
      }
      if (d <= e && i > 0){
      feldz[i][j] = d;
      System.out.print(feldz[i][j] + " |");
     }
      if (i > 0 && j == 10) {
      d++;
      }

      }
      System.out.println("");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
          feldb[i][j] = ' ';
          System.out.print(feldb[i][j] + " |");
        }
        if (i > 0 && j == 0){
          feldb[i][j] = ' ';
            System.out.print(feldb[i][j] + " |");
        }

        if (c > f) {
          c = 'A';
        }
        if(c <= f && j > 0){
          feldb[i][j] = c;
          System.out.print(feldb[i][j] + " |");
          c++;
        }
        if (j == 10){
        System.out.println("");
        }

      }

  }



  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need *array* to *print the maze* , `nested loops` is enough for that. `2d Array` is only required to `store the input`. *Please try the below code:*

```
        int size = 10;
        int [][] maze = new int[size][size];
        while (true){
            System.out.print(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.print('|');
                System.out.print((char) ('A' + i));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    System.out.print('|');
                    if(maze[i][j] > 0) {
                        System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(' ');
                    }
                }
            }
            int row = -1;
            int col = -1;
            System.out.println("\nEnter CoOrdinates");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if(input.length() == 2) {
                char charAt = input.charAt(0);
                if(charAt >= 'A' && charAt <= 'A'+size-1) {
                    col = charAt-'A';
                }
                charAt = input.charAt(1);
                if(charAt >= '0' && charAt <= '0'+size-1) {
                    row = charAt-'0';
                }
                if(row != -1 && col != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Action");
                    input = scanner.nextLine();
                    int action = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    maze[row][col] = action;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
                }
            }
        }
```